# How can I derive the inequality $f(x)\overline{f(y)}\leq c^{2}K(x,y)$

Tags: functional-analysis, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

I'm currently reading $\textit{An Introduction do the Theory of Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Spaces}$ by $\textit{Vern I. Paulsen}$.

Let $f\in \mathcal{H}(K)$  with $||f||$=c. The following inequality is used frequently: $$f(x)\overline{f(y)}\leq c^{2}K(x,y)$$
Why does this inequality hold?

Using the Cauchy-Schwarz-Inequality I get
$$ |f(x)\overline{f(y)}|=|\langle f,k_{x}\rangle \langle k_{y},f \rangle| \leq \langle f,f\rangle \langle k_{x},k_{x} \rangle \langle k_{y},k_{y} \rangle\langle f,f\rangle =c^{2}\langle k_{x},k_{x} \rangle \langle k_{y},k_{y}\rangle$$
which is not exactly what I what.
Any suggestions?

Comment: what does $K(x,y)$ mean?

Comment: $K$ is the reproducing kernel for $\mathcal{H}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a typo. What Paulsen means is $(f(x)\overline{f(y)})\leq (K(x,y))$, or in other words, $(x,y)\mapsto K(x,y)-f(x)\overline{f(y)}$ is a kernel function. That this is true is content of Theorem 4.15 (at least in his [notes](https://www.math.uh.edu/%7Evern/rkhs.pdf) online).

Comment: I'm referring to the proofs of 5.1 (and 5.7 which is not included in the online notes). My understanding is, that there it is an inequality.

Comment: As a pointwise inequality it does not make sense. First, both sides can be complex. But even if they are real, it is usually wrong. Take $X=\{1,2\}$, $f=1$ and $K(x,y)=\delta_{x,y}$ for example. In the proof of 5.1 it should be interpreted as I said in my answer.

Comment: I guess you are right. But how should I interpret the expression $f(x_{i})f(x_{j})\leq||f||^2K(x_{i},x_{j})$ in the proof of 4.15?

Comment: The matrix with entries $\lVert f\rVert^2 K(x_i,x_j)-f(x_i) \overline{f(x_j)}$ is positive semi-definite.